# Attaching database to SQL Server 2016 using Management Studio 13

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016

When using the right-click option on 'databases' the 'Attach' option is not listed.

[CODE EXAMPLE WITH ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CghAJ.jpg)

I'm wondering if someone else has seen this before.

I also get an error when I run this code instead:

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb 
ON (FILENAME = 'C:\databasefile.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
GO
```

My SQL Server version is

```
select @@version
```

Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Jul 10 2018 21:38:33

[Attach option is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPy4U.jpg)

Comment: We'd have to know the exact edition and version of the SQL Server instance SSMS is connected to. Please open a query window, run this command: `SELECT @@VERSION`, and paste the result into your question. As text, not as an image.

Comment: Also, an mdt file is... an Access File: https://www.lifewire.com/mdt-file-2621977

Comment: .mdt should be .mdf for sure

Comment: Yes - I did use .mdf - and I edited the code string above just now changing from .mdt to .mdf. Same error still occurs.